# postgresql - add boolean column to table set default

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is this proper postgresql syntax to add a column to a table with a default value of `false`

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD "priv_user" BIT
ALTER priv_user SET DEFAULT '0'
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you want a bit column or an actual `boolean` column?

Answer (score 497, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE users
  ADD COLUMN "priv_user" BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
```

you can also directly specify NOT NULL

```
ALTER TABLE users
  ADD COLUMN "priv_user" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE;
```

**UPDATE**: following is only true for versions before postgresql 11.

As Craig mentioned on filled tables it is more efficient to split it into steps:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN priv_user BOOLEAN;
UPDATE users SET priv_user = 'f';
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN priv_user SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN priv_user SET DEFAULT FALSE;
```

Comment: Note that if your table is big this can take a long time and lock the table for the entire time. It's faster to split it into steps: add the column without a default with `ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN priv_user BOOLEAN;`, then `UPDATE users SET priv_user = 'f';` and finally if you need to `ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN priv_user SET NOT NULL;`.

Comment: The approach that is split into steps is not adding a default value. Is it still faster to add a "DEFAULT 'f'" in a separate step?

Comment: Yes adding the default in a seperate step is only a meta data operation and thus very fast.

Comment: what does it - 'a meta data operation'? In what sense and why  it is different than setting the value in one go? Thanks

Comment: Is the case important? Some guys mention that type should written as 'boolean' - BOOLEAN is not correct (or allowed)

Comment: The actual rules are that keywords and unquoted identifiers are not case sensitive so BOOLEAN is allowed thought internally postgresql will use boolean. I tend to write standard types and SQL keywords in uppercase, I do use lowercase for all my own identifiers.

Comment: @CraigRinger Shouldn't the performant case be:
```ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN priv_user BOOLEAN;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN priv_user SET DEFAULT FALSE;
UPDATE users SET priv_user = 'f';
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN priv_user SET NOT NULL;
```

Otherwise there might come another row in between statement 2 and 3 which does not have the value, which would cause `ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN priv_user SET NOT NULL;` to fail?

Answer (score 28):

If you want an actual boolean column:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD "priv_user" boolean DEFAULT false;
```

Comment: Note: not all versions of Postgres support this being defined in one line.

Answer (score 20):

Just for future reference, if you *already* have a boolean column and you just want to add a default do:

```
ALTER TABLE users
  ALTER COLUMN priv_user SET DEFAULT false;
```

Comment: Are there performance implications for this operation for large tables? Specifically changing a default value to another value without changing the type, on postgres 9.6

Comment: Good question @CPS. I don't know the answer but since this doesn't do anything to existing rows (it's not like a NOT NULL), this shouldn't take any time, regardless of the size of the table.

Answer (score 8):

In psql alter column query syntax like this

```
Alter table users add column priv_user boolean default false ;
```

boolean value **(true-false)** save in DB like **(t-f)** value .

Answer (score 6):

If you are using postgresql then you have to use column type BOOLEAN in lower case as boolean.

ALTER TABLE users ADD "priv_user" boolean DEFAULT false;